# Children Frames of a Label disappear on changing bg color of Label; don't reappear unless window is resized

Tags: python, tkinter

Some background:
I have a class that inherits from `tk.Label`; basically, a Label widget that has some extra methods tuned to my taste.

I have two design modes for the label, and a function switching between them. Mode 1 is a simple look with black text; mode 2 is a look that has two empty blue frames inside the label, solely for design purposes (but are required).
The custom-widget (let's name it `Cell`) is bound to a function that changes the bg color (no matter which mode) of the `Cell` when clicked, and reverts when released.

Now, the situation:
**Case I:-** *When `Cell` object is in "mode 1"*
When the label is clicked and released, bg color changes respectively. Normal behaviour

**Case II:-** *When `Cell` object is in "mode 2"*
There are initially two frames *in* the frame.
When the label is clicked, bg color changes alright, but the frames suddenly disappear. The frames don't reappear, unless window is resized.
I doubted if the frames were sent behind of the `Cell` object (which seems absurd to me) and tried `.lift()`ing it. No success. Then I tried `.update()` and `.update_idletasks()` on the `Cell` object. No success again.
I want the frames to not disappear when I do `.config(bg="new bg")` and not need to resize the window just to make them reappear (don't know why this is needed)

Is this the way it is supposed to work - hiding the frames for some reason on configuring the label attributes? If so, what can be a way around it?

---

Minimal code attached below:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def setMode1():
    f1.place_forget()
    f2.place_forget()

def setMode2():
    f1.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    f2.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1, rely=0.9)

on_click = lambda event: Cell.config(bg="#9999CC")
on_release = lambda event: Cell.config(bg="#CCCCFF")

window = tk.Tk()
window.wm_geometry("240x380")
Cell = tk.Label(window, text="TEXT", bg="#CCCCFF")
Cell.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
Cell.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_release)
f1 = tk.Frame(Cell, bg="#66AAFF")
f2 = tk.Frame(Cell, bg="#66AAFF")
Cell.place(width=240, height=200, y=25)
tk.Button(window, text="Mode 1", command=setMode1).place(width=100, height=40, x=70, y=250)
tk.Button(window, text="Mode 2", command=setMode2).place(width=100, height=40, x=70, y=315)
window.mainloop()
```

---

(I had posted the same question earlier but realised it was way too verbose. This is a shorter version)
Any inputs to resolve the issue would be highly appreciated.

---

EDIT: Both - the alternate solution of the accepted answer, as well as the suggestion by @Eli Harold to tweak the config method of the class to un-place and re-place the frames - worked. However the accepted solution has accomplished it in its alternate solution without use of extra widgets/commands/tweaking.

Comment: Are you running on OSX?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am on windows 10 and have all of the same issues.

Comment: My specifications: Windows 7 64-bit, Python 3.8.10, tkinter v8.6

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. When you say _"When Cell object is in design 2"_, do you mean "when I click the "Mode 2" button"?

Comment: yeah exactly.. i think i confused you by interchanging mode and design at places

Comment: As a generalisation (mine is a specific case) it seems, whenever the label has a child placed, and the label is later config-ed for some reason, the child(ren) disappear. I'm not sure if they are pushed below the label (how could that happen, anyways) coz nothing happens when u lift them. And its definitely not `forget`-ing its place information. If needed, maybe an issue can be raised to concerned team stating this issue

Comment: Hmmm. When I click on "Mode 2" I see the two frames at the top and bottom of the label. When I click the label, the background of the label changes but I still see the frames. Is something else supposed to happen?

Comment: Well, the observation is that when the label is configured to change bg, text, etc. its children frames disappear (in this or any such example where there are frames, etc. INSIDE a label). What are your specifications? It happened everytime on my PC and seemed to happen on @EliHarold 's pc as he stated above

Comment: @BryanOakley yes when I click mode 2 and then the label with the original code the frames disappear. what os are you on bryan?

Comment: @EliHarold I don't understand, why are you responding to Bryan's questions towards the OP? Is it your alternate account? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I was explaining to him that OXS was not the issue because it am not running it but still see the issue, I was supporting the validity of the OP's question. My most recent comment was to explain what I see because I am confused at why Bryan is not seeing the same.

Comment: I am on OSX. Maybe this is a windows-specific problem?

Comment: @BryanOakley Very much probable that it's windows-specific. Are there other Windows users out there who face this? I have a feeling that this can be raised in an appropriate forum/website so that it can be brought to notice of the developers of tcl/tk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Label` is not designed for holding other widgets.  Better use a frame to hold the label and the two frames instead:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def setMode1():
    f1.place_forget()
    f2.place_forget()

def setMode2():
    f1.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    f2.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1, rely=0.9)

on_click = lambda event: Cell.config(bg="#9999CC")
on_release = lambda event: Cell.config(bg="#CCCCFF")

window = tk.Tk()
window.wm_geometry("240x380")

# outer frame to hold the label and the two frames
container = tk.Frame(window)
container.place(width=240, height=200, y=25)

Cell = tk.Label(container, text="TEXT", bg="#CCCCFF")
Cell.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

Cell.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
Cell.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_release)

f1 = tk.Frame(container, bg="#66AAFF")
f2 = tk.Frame(container, bg="#66AAFF")

tk.Button(window, text="Mode 1", command=setMode1).place(width=100, height=40, x=70, y=250)
tk.Button(window, text="Mode 2", command=setMode2).place(width=100, height=40, x=70, y=315)

window.mainloop()
```

---

Another suggestion is create the two sub-frames children of `window` and use `in_=Cell` inside `.place()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def setMode1():
    f1.place_forget()
    f2.place_forget()

def setMode2():
    # place inside Cell
    f1.place(in_=Cell, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    f2.place(in_=Cell, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1, rely=0.9)

on_click = lambda event: Cell.config(bg="#9999CC")
on_release = lambda event: Cell.config(bg="#CCCCFF")

window = tk.Tk()
window.wm_geometry("240x380")
Cell = tk.Label(window, text="TEXT", bg="#CCCCFF")
Cell.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
Cell.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_release)
f1 = tk.Frame(window, bg="#66AAFF") # child of window instead
f2 = tk.Frame(window, bg="#66AAFF")
Cell.place(width=240, height=200, y=25)
tk.Button(window, text="Mode 1", command=setMode1).place(width=100, height=40, x=70, y=250)
tk.Button(window, text="Mode 2", command=setMode2).place(width=100, height=40, x=70, y=315)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you responding to my query. *"Label is not designed for holding other widgets"* - I can understand how they are not meant to be used that way. However I am having 42 of the same kind of Labels and the program is already visibly slow. I wouldn't risk to add 42 frames that hold 42 labels (aah!) on the screen. I have many other tkinter widgets on the screen and tkinter functions seem to weigh the cpu down :-(

Comment: For some reference (about 42 labels, etc), please refer to the comments of the answer by @Eli Harold

Comment: _"Label is not designed for holding other widgets."_ - while it's true they weren't _designed_ for it, they certainly can be. Though, if all you need is a container, the Frame is the better choice in most cases.

Comment: @a_n: I can't imagine a UI with only a few hundred widgets being a drag on the CPU, unless you're doing something very inefficiently.

Comment: *"can't imagine a UI with only a few hundred widgets being a drag"* - I somewhat disagree. I don't see a problem with any app (I mean compiled .exe files) with any number of widgets causing a CPU drag. (my cpu is very old, i3 2328M) But tkinter has been causing issues with the simplest gui having 40-50 identical labels each with its bg color. So it seems evident to me that if I create too many frames for an already slow interpreter (compared to a compiler) it would be difficult for low end cpus to handle. Hence I wanted to keep the load at a minimum.

Comment: @a_n could you not have one frame to hold all the sub frames rather than 42 separate frames? then you could just choose which sub frames were `place`d and which were `place_forget`ten...

Comment: By *"one frame to hold all the sub frames"* you mean the blue frames in the original code, I hope. I would actually like to access these subframes by storing as `Cell<n>.frame1/2` rather than having to do some math to figure out which frame would be the one on which label whenever I want to place it. You can say I'm lazy, or am out of time to submit the project LOL. Anyways, I've worked around and went into the .config() method itself to un-place and re-place the frames (using the global variable idea thing) and it works. I would like to mark this question as 'solved' or something.

Comment: @a_n You wouldn't have to do any math simply save MM:01 as `f01` and the 2nd date as `f02` etc. then just place `f02a` and `f02b` when it is the second of the month etc.

Comment: @a_n something like `if currDate == n: fna.place fnb.place for n in dates`. Obviously my syntax if off, but you get the idea.

Comment: @a_n Alternative suggestion added.

Comment: woah your alternate suggestion works too. @Eli Harold I will have to mark this answer as accepted as it could suggest a workaround without initialization of extra widgets. No offense meant :-)

Comment: @a_n no problem at all I was confused and thought these comments were on my answer that is why I said that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The frames are just being pushed behind the background of the label. You can add some code like this to fix the issue:

```
import tkinter as tk

def setMode1():
    global mode
    f1.place_forget()
    f2.place_forget()
    mode = 1

def setMode2():
    global mode
    f1.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    f2.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1, rely=0.9)
    mode = 2

on_click = lambda event: Cell.config(bg="#9999CC")
def on_release(event):
    Cell.config(bg="#CCCCFF")
    if mode == 2:
        f1.place_forget()
        f2.place_forget()
        f1.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
        f2.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1, rely=0.9)

mode = 0
window = tk.Tk()
window.wm_geometry("240x380")
Cell = tk.Label(window, text="TEXT", bg="#CCCCFF")
Cell.bind("<Button-1>", on_click)
Cell.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_release)
f1 = tk.Frame(Cell, bg="#66AAFF")
f2 = tk.Frame(Cell, bg="#66AAFF")
Cell.place(width=240, height=200, y=25)
tk.Button(window, text="Mode 1", command=setMode1).place(width=100, height=40, x=70, y=250)
tk.Button(window, text="Mode 2", command=setMode2).place(width=100, height=40, x=70, y=315)
window.mainloop()
```

This just adds a variable `mode` that tells `on_release` how to treat the frames. It basically forces the program to add the frames when it needs to.

Comment: If this is not the desired effect please explain further. @a_n

Comment: The workaround seems very valid. But scale it up to 42 of these Labels on screen at once (which is the case with my application), wouldn't it demand a lot of processing to add 42 mode variables, one for each instance of the label?

Comment: If you need clarification on the nature of my app, kindly mention

Comment: Ok, it seems like this problem of the frames (or any child widget) of the label disappearing occurs **whenever** the label is configured using .config() or .configure() (serious issue!). I tried changing text instead of colour and it still happens. Those frames don't come back until window is resized. Seems like more of a tkinter issue. Is it supposed to be this way? Does the above said happen on other systems too?

Comment: @a_n I understand your concern, but I don't think it would be a huge issue because you are only changing a mode variable one at a time and you only have one mode variable regardless of how many labels, you can just send the same mode variable to all of them. With that said, I believe there should be a better solution than mine I just do not know of one.

Comment: @a_n yeah I think it is a tkinter issue because I have had similar issues and I always have implemented a work around like I presented here. It has a lot of weird behavior where widgets are updated and the view changes after commands are run. I wish there was a better way also and I assume there is... This is all I know of though.

Comment: _"wouldn't it demand a lot of processing to add 42 mode variables"_ - if you have tens of thousands you might notice performance issues. handling 42 is trivial.

Comment: @BryanOakley exactly, but regardless the issue should not come from the mode variable. It would most likely come from the place and place_forget calls.

Comment: Um, feels like I gotta reveal my app after all. Its a calendar app with 7 columns of these labels. By default they are in a design resembling mode 1 above. I then check if today's date is present on the grid shown, and pin point the label to change the design (mode 2). I am not sure how to proceed with this problem - whether to introduce a mode variable for each label, or to use some sort of global variable pointing which label needs mode 2, and if so, how I should approach it. The window itself is already a bit slow with so many variables and labels.

Comment: hmm. i see your point with *"if you have tens of thousands"* @BryanOakley

Comment: @a_n I see what your goal is now, and yes I would recommend one variable pointing to which label needs mode 2 rather than a mode variable in general. but again adding a variable like this will be trivial for processing. It will be the tkinter functions that start to weigh you down.

Comment: BTW, as I said the problem is being caused whenever I call config for whatever reasons. Now I am not sure in how many places I might be calling config. I wonder how I'll manage when I'm config-ing a label that "at-the-moment" has the mode 2 (with the frames). Would you recommend adding a .config method to the Cell class (mentioned in the question that I'm originally using classes) that will handle this?

Comment: @a_n That could work, because that method could be where you forget and place the frames.

Comment: I couldn't wait so I made the changes right away. I'm happy to say that it's working... satisfyingly... sorta... There is a small time duration of say 100 ms where the frames are not there and then they appear again (and this works wherever I am config-ing the bg for it) I think that delay can be forgiven. Thanks for suggesting the idea of un-placing and re-placing the widgets :-)